# How to find public address through private key on TRON

Tags: private-key, public-key, cryptocurrency, wallet, tron

How can I find user **public** address from his **private key** ?
Already I found a way to convert public to hex Address also private to hex and reverse
but get stuck in this one !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [TronWeb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tronweb), you can call this function:

```js
const address = tronWeb.address.fromPrivateKey(newAccount.privateKey);
```

That code comes from one of [TronWeb's tests](https://github.com/tronprotocol/tronweb/blob/cb2be227eaaa6dc9895052e7553c12e0e3ac6145/test/utils/accounts.test.js#L17)

Comment: any equivalent for tronpy? I can't find this in the tronpy docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python, [the official tronpy document](https://tronpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keys.html) doesn't mentioned this. However, you can find the answer by yourself.

Open ipython from terminal, create a key object from a random key, input the key variable name and press tab twice, you will see all the attributes and functions of the object.

```
import tronpy


my_random_key = tronpy.keys.PrivateKey.random()
my_key = tronpy.keys.PrivateKey.fromhex(my_random_key)
my_key.public_key.to_base58check_address()
```

Answer (score 0):

for bitcoin you need use this package to find public key => dart_wif

```
print('hex :::::: ${HEX.encode(index.privateKey!)}');

WIF decoded = WIF(version: 128, privateKey: index.privateKey!, compressed: true);

String key = wif.encode(decoded);
print(key);
```

Comment: Is there anyone who can tell us the algorithm?